# polling on a promise to have always fresh data

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to fetch an endpoint that return a json object to display the result in my app.

this json return a list of online users, so i need to refresh this data every X seconds/minutes.

i've writed this code:

```
function getJustBlabData(url) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
          const getData = fetch(url);
          resolve(getData)
      })
    }

    getJustBlabData('https://justblab.com/baxf/widget.php?q=online_usr')
      .then((res) => res.json()
        .then((data) => {
          this.justBlab = data
          this.loading = false
          console.log(this.justBlab)
        })
      )
```

ive tried with setInterval like:

```
 function getJustBlabData(url) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setInterval(() => {
          const getData = fetch(url);
          resolve(getData)
        }, 1000)
      })
    }
```

but i'm doing something wrong, but what?

Comment: Promises may only be resolved once. You'll need to rethink how you handle the responses from your requests

Comment: a promise can only "settle" (resolve or reject) once - your attempt `resolves` the same Promise each time, so the second and subsequent resolves do nothing - wonder if *Generators* help (never used them myself!)

Comment: what is the correct way to get always fresh data after x seconds?

Comment: fetch it again. Without more context to your code, that's about as much as I'm willing to say

Comment: what do you mean for context? the context is how i can get this data refreshed after X seconds

Comment: The return value of `getJustBlabData` is not useful. You'll need to think of another way to handle the responses

Comment: `how i can get this data refreshed after X seconds` fetch it again after X seconds

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, use `fetch` directly, since your `getJustBlabData` function is essentially just return `fetch(url)` wrapped in a new Promise - but since `fetch` already returns a Promise, there is no need for that code at all

i.e.

```
function getJustBlabData(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      const getData = fetch(url);
      resolve(getData)
  })
}
getJustBlabData(url).then ....
```

is equivalent (but in a lot of ways worse for error handling) to

```
fetch(url).then ....
```

If you want to do something every X seconds, do the whole thing in the interval

Like this

```
setInterval(() => {
  this.loading = true;
  fetch('https://justblab.com/baxf/widget.php?q=online_usr')
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
      this.justBlab = data;
      this.loading = false;
      console.log(this.justBlab);
  });
}, 1000);
```

Now, `this.justBlab` gets updated every second

Note: Also, I've flattened your .then pyramid into a .then chain

to address the situation where requests could take longer than a second

```
(() => {
    const processBlab = () => {
    this.loading = true;
    fetch('https://justblab.com/baxf/widget.php?q=online_usr')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        this.justBlab = data;
        this.loading = false;
        console.log(this.justBlab);
        setTimeout(() => processBlab(), 1000);
    });
    processBlab();
})();
```

Only reason I put that all in a IIFE is to preserve `this` - as there is no context in the question as to what `this` is

Comment: If it takes longer than 1 second for the server to respond it appears this would pile up requests.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss true - an issue with the original code as well - not my problem, question was how to do this every X seconds, answer supplied

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - added a possible solution - messier than it needs to be, but `this` is preserved to whatever it would be in the original question

Comment: Yes, I noted you addressed the OP syntax issue on `.then((res) => res.json()` to be `.then((res) => res.json())`  - pointing that our for the OP here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a promise to create a "wait" function and the restart the process again (get a new set of data) once that completes.
Here I used a 5 second delay between each cycle.

Doing it this way, if the server takes 10 seconds to reply this will do a new request 5 seconds after that response and avoids piling up requests.

```js
let delayMSTime = 5000;
let howMany = 1;

function sleep(time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

function getJustBlabData(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const getData = fetch(url);
    resolve(getData);
  })
}

function GoGetEm(myDelay) {
  getJustBlabData('https://justblab.com/baxf/widget.php?q=online_usr')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.justBlab = data;
      this.loading = false;
      console.log(this.justBlab);
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("sleeeping for the "+howMany+" time:" + myDelay);
      sleep(myDelay).then(() => {
      howMany++;
        GoGetEm(myDelay);
        console.clear();
      });
    });
}
GoGetEm(delayMSTime);
```

Comment: the problem is that if i try to map and display this... doesn't appear. my code to display is https://jsfiddle.net/tbjnyo4L/

Comment: How to display that data I currently just console log is an entirely new question since this was about the fetch/wait/re-fetch